# Value from intrerval

Tags: matlab

there is a C variable, which has 300 samples and there is a range on X axis, on which the variable is spread. I need to sort the C samples and establish, to what interval it belongs to. The X range is divided to 100 intervals (%). So I need to create a script, which will take interval between int(i) and int(i+1), proceses whole C and save the suitable C(i) into a variable D and make an average from it. Thanks a lot. Tom

Comment: What do you mean with "proceses whole C and save the suitable C(i) into a variable D and make an average from it"?

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what MATLAB `histc` function does.

Comment: Yes, something similar like histc. I have some points which have the coordinates x,y. I've got them from my gps and there is quite big noise in them. So I need to need to reconstruct my track. And I want to make an average of them on each interval (%).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a combination of `histc` and `accumarray`. First let's generate some data -

```
>> X = rand(3000, 1);            // 3000 samples of the variable X
>> C = X + randn(3000, 1);       // 3000 samples of C, which depends on X
>> edges = linspace(0, 1, 101);  // edges of the bins for X
```

Now you can find out which bin each observation falls into using the second output of `histc`

```
>> [tmp, bin] = histc(X, edges);
```

Finally, you can create a vector `Cavg` using `accumarray` to iterate over each bin and take their average

```
>> Cavg = accumarray(bin, C, [101,1], @mean, NaN);
```

You can plot the observations and their average to check that you got what you expected

```
>> plot(X, C, '.');
>> hold on;
>> plot(edges, Cavg, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Beat me for seconds. I suggest you add `NaN` as a fifth argument to `accumarray`, so that it will return `NaN` for empty intervals

Comment: Nice addition - thanks!

Comment: Thak you a lot, it's what I wanted to do. But when I try to feed it with my data it returns an error _Error using accumarray
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts._ 
My code now looks like:
%in variable C are the coordinates the "X" in 2nd cell and "Y"in  3rd cell
`X = C(:,2);            
D = C(:,3);       
edges = y_min:y_percent:y_max;  

[tmp, bin] = histc(X, edges);

Cavg = accumarray(bin, D, [101,1], @mean);

plot(X, D, '.');
hold on;
plot(edges, Cavg, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);`

Comment: sorry I don't know how to use formating on this web

Comment: @TomasFlegl I'll take a closer look later today, but probably the error is that at least some of the values in `bin` are zero, which indicates that there are values in `X` that are outside the range of `edges` (can you check that?)

Comment: +1 thnks, wrong edges ... thanks a lot. now I've to edit it for my use.